# Want to learn assembly, confused about where to start

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit

Just for the hell of it, i've taken an interest in learning assembly.  The problem is I can't find a good starting point...

There seems to be a lot of assemblers available (FASM, NASM, YASM, MASM) but each has their own separate syntax, commands, and features.  FASM seems to be the most convenient since it can compile executables without a linker but I haven't been able to find any tutorials to start me off.  All the "Hello World" examples i've seen are 16 or 32-bit, but i'm running on 64-bit Windows so none of them work.  The Windows examples included with FASM work but I'm not looking to get into Windows programming right from the start, I want to grasp the basics first.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you want to grasp the basics first, would you consider making some simple devices with a PIC or AVR based microprocessor?  You would be using a much simpler instruction set and could probably pick things up quicker.

Comment: @Jonathon: Paradoxically, their simplicity can make them harder to learn to use. For example, without a multiply or divide instruction, you need to write a (somewhat non-trivial) routine to handle that.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to learn to read assembly, I recommend learning to use WInDbg or IDA Pro as your primary debugger - learning not only what the instructions do, but how a C++ compiler idiomatically translates your source code into assembly will help you to learn far better than if you're doing contrived 100% assembly examples

Answer (score 4):

I am no expert on assembly but it is an essential thing, to at least be familiar with, in computing.  In a computer engineering class we used [SPIM](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/spim.html) by James Laurus, a MIPS architecture simulator for windows.  I think it is a good starting point.  You can find a MIPS cheat-sheet via Google search, as well as some tutorials.

Assembly is cool because it is essentially machine language.  Happy hacking!

Comment: MIPS assembly is just plain simpler and easier to learn than x86's, so it's a very good place to start.

Comment: MIPS assembly is essentially obsolete. If you want something nice and don't mind it's being obsolete, learn PDP-11 assembly language.

Comment: MIPS is a little closer to the style of RISC used by modern processors, and there's better simulators and teaching tools for it than there are for (say) PPC. I learned on Sparc first, and yes it's obsolete, but the skills transferred well enough that I was able to pick up MIPS in a day afterwards (when we were still selling consumer electronics with MIPS in them).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: my ADSL router right here has a MIPS processor. PowerPC is very similar to MIPS.

Comment: obsolete?  consumer electronics currently ship in consumer electronics.  Nothing can touch ARM at the moment but mips is by no means obsolete.  no more obsolete than the x86 instruction set.

Answer (score 3):

32-bit examples should work even though your host OS is 64-bit.

On top of that is the difference between a 32- and a 64-bit Hello World just 2 characters:

```
include 'win64ax.inc'
```

vs

```
include 'win32ax.inc'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best x86 ASM introduction I have found:

http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/

There is a pdf version of his book on that page. It starts at the very basics and works its way up. I got all of the fundamental ASM knowledge that I needed just with this book (stack frame creation, calling conventions, c interop, just to name a couple).

Answer (score 1):

It's just boring to learn assembler without any goal.

Could I recommend you to buy any robot kit? As I know RoboSavvy robots are managed by assmeblers / C .. Others may have only DSL.

http://robosavvy.com/site/

P.S. I've learned assembler when I was in need to cheat in games. But today I would choose robot kits.

Comment: What you mean is "I personally think that it's just boring to learn assembly without any goal."

Answer (score 1):

If you are a bigner and wants to learn the assembly better to get ASM knowledge 1st.
secondly try to learn the basic logic behind each code.
3.enjoy the language when try to learn if u r intrested otherwise leave it.